# Apple AppStore app rejection and Freedom of speech/press

Tags: internet, intellectual-property, freedom-of-speech

My question relates to one Apple App Store guideline:

> Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its metadata is not appropriate on the App Store.

I understand this to mean that it is prohibited to show any information about other platforms in the application. So, the developer is prohibited from mentioning such words as "Android, Windows, Linux, BlackBerry OS, Web OS" and many others.

I am developing a technology news application that aims to include news about other platforms on the market. Per this guideline I am allowed to show only Apple-related news in the app.

The app has been rejected.

How does this rejection relate to the freedom of speech and press, which is present in many countries' laws as a basic human right. Can it be considered as a censorship? Or if Apple owns the platform, it can dictate any rules and I have to obey them as a developer?

Comment: Did Apple explicitly reject the app for violating _that_ guideline?

Comment: Yes. They provided a screenshot, showing news with "MS Windows" word

Comment: Out of interest, did you appeal the decision?

Comment: Nope, I just implemented client-side (iOS only) content filtering. List of prohibited words is quite long and counts for more than 20.

Comment: The nice political solution would be to replace all references with `[CENSORED]` with a link to a page that explains the situation.

Comment: @AndrewRay Which will get you just as rejected. Plus they can cancel your developer contract. They can set requirements for doing business with you. You don't have to obey them, but if you don't, they don't publish your app. You can always write Android apps or Windows apps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taking the US as an example, the [Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) states

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

Congress or a state government hasn't prohibited you from comparing platforms.  Another private entity has.  And, that's fine.  You're free to launch the app as a separate website, or print out the flyers and hand them to people on the bus, or publish your own monthly magazine comparing various platforms, so you still have freedom of speech and of the press.

As an example, if you write a letter about how great the government of North Korea is to the letters department at Stamp Collectors Magazine, and they don't publish it, have they violated your human rights?

The app store restriction may be quite dumb.  After all, the built-in web browser allows the reading of the exact same news.  But there's no law against being dumb.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it clarified the case to me.

I would like to ask you a question about using a WebView inside the app.
There are two parts of the application, the native one and the Web one. It just shows web pages as a regular browser. Can I still mention other platforms in Web part? Or it is Apple-specific question and it is imposible to answer according to the law?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy: That's entirely up to Apple.  This is a matter of their policy, not the law.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up @feetwet, I've been away from computers for a few days.